# How call React's setState function from outside of any component, like a utility function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app where I want to move the read, write operations to a utility file i.e. away from component. I am trying to do it this way.

component.js

```
import { saveData } from './utils/fileSave.js';

class App extends Component {
    saveContent() {
        saveData(this.setState, data);
    }
    ...
}
```

utils/fileSave.js

```
const saveData = (setState, data) => {
    setState(data);
}
```

However, that leads to an error, saying 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'updater' of undefined'

Not sure if this is the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to bind `setState` before passing it to an external function.

`saveData(this.setState.bind(this), data);`

Comment: Btw, I think `saveData` makes things unclear. `this.setState(data)` is better

Answer (score 2):

Need to bind `this` to `setState`.

```
 saveData(this.setState.bind(this), data);
```

Working [`codesandbox demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/m50x8y382y)

Comment: Arrow function doesn't work like you describe. You're not removing invoking context because there was none. It's called like `saveData(...)`, not `saveData.call(this, ...)`.

Comment: @estus arrow function always refer to to lexical scope which is `global this` here

Comment: `this` isn't used in the code you've posted, so regular vs arrow doesn't affect anything.

Comment: when setState is called which nothing but setState,inside setState there is call to `this.somefun`.Now here `this` will refer to global one.I pointing here

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You could try the code you've proposed. Both original and this one will fail.

Comment: @estus is correct. Both the ways are failing with the same message.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good idea to extract methods that rely on the context (component instance) to utility functions, primarily because this requires to take additional actions to make them work.

Since `this.setState` is passed as a callback, it should be either bound to proper context:

```
saveData(this.setState.bind(this), data);
```

Or utility function should be defined as regular function *and* be called with proper context:

```
function saveData(data) {
    this.setState(data);
}

class App extends Component {
    saveContent() {
        saveData.call(this, data);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the case where inheritance is preferable because it allows to get proper context naturally. `saveData` can be reused via a mixin.

It can be assigned directly to class prototype:

```
function saveData(data) {
    this.setState(data);
}

class App extends Component {
    // saveData = saveData
    // is less efficient but also a correct way to do this
    saveContent() {
        this.saveData(data);
    }
    ...
}
App.prototype.saveData = saveData;
```

Or be applied via a decorator:

```
function saveData(target) {
    return class extends target {
        saveData(data) {
            this.setState(data);
        }
    }
}


@saveData
class App extends Component {
    saveContent() {
        this.saveData(data);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the bind function with arrow function will allow it works like a callback.

```
saveData((newState) => this.setState(newState), data);
```