# How to inject functions that change component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conventions

I want to keep some functions outside of my component for easier testing. However, I cannot change state with these functions because they cannot reference the component's state directly.

So I currently have the hacky solution where I set the function to a variable then call `this.setState`. Is there a better convention/more efficient way to do this?

Example function code in Tester.js:

```
const tester = () => {
  return 'new data';
}

export default tester;
```

Example component code in App.js (without imports):

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let newData = tester();
        this.setState({ data: newData })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>{this.state.data}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: *I want to keep some functions outside of my component for easier testing* - this is wrong motivation. This benefits reusability but not testability. `tester` class method can be mocked on class prototype when needed. It still can be reusable being a part of component class, as shown here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51631079/3731501 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind your tester function like this (this approach doesn't work with arrow functions):

```
function tester() {
  this.setState({ data: 'new Data' });
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: '',
    };
    this.tester = tester.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tester();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.data}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I would prefer a cleaner approach, where you don't need your function to access *this* (also works with arrow functions):

```
function tester(prevState, props) {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    data: 'new Data',
  };
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(tester);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.data}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can pass a function to `setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that will return a new object representing the new state of your component. So you could do this:

```
const tester = (previousState, props) => {
  return {
    ...previousState,
    data: 'new data',
  };
}

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState(tester)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>{this.state.data}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

The reason being that you now have access to your component's previous state and props in your `tester` function.

If you just need access to unchanging *static* placeholder values inside of your app, for example Lorem Ipsum or something else, then just export your data as a JSON object and use it like that:

```
// testData.js
export const testData = {
  foo: "bar",
  baz: 7,
};

...

// In your app.jsx file
import testData from "./testData.js";

const qux = testData.foo; // "bar"

etc.
```